# Allocate and deallocate Memory to UIView at run time

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiview

I am making an App, in which has

MyViewController1

MyViewController2 + 9 UIView within it (MyView1, MyView2, MyView3, MyView4, MyView5, MyView6, MyView7, MyView8, MyView9).

**And Manage hide and showing of each view later on according to my requirements
as all the view are not needed initially, they are needed on button clicks ...**

So what i have done is ->

Step 1) added each view in myViewController2.xib(views are not added inside view of viewController2 ..i.e they are not child of viewController2)

Step 2) IBOutlet UIView *myView(1..9); in MyViewController2.h

Step 3) property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView(1..9) in MyViewController2.h

Step 4) synthesize myView(1..9) in MyViewController2.m

```
viewDidLoad(){ 
    myView1.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, y, y)//any Value
    [self.view addSubView:myView1]; //added as child to this view

    //I did for all the view

}
```

Step 5) Now applied alpha =0/1, transitions, any other property according to requirement..

Everything is fine....

But now My App is taking too much memory, whenever this page is being load...

So now solution i thought

Allocate memory to each UIView only when needed i.e on click of button and
when it is not needed deallocate the memory for that view.

how to do that as my all 9 views have been created using IB, so how to load view at run time from interface builder???

Please Suggest any other solution also if there...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add views at runtime if they are created in IB.  All objects created in IB are alloc/inited before even `viewDidLoad` is called.  If you want the view created at runtime, you will have to create it programatically, not in IB.  (Aadhira's suggestion will work nicely if you choose to go this route.  But, you do have to make sure that you are not creating the views in IB.  Also, the views cannot be retained properties.  Otherwise, removing them from the superview will not release them.)

However, that may not be necessary.  As long as you are not putting any content (e.g. images) in your views, they may not be taking up much memory.  You could create the views in IB, but add content to them programatically, as needed, and release that content programatically, when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

So whenever you want a view to be shown, init that and show that. Also set a tag for that view. When you want to show another view, remove the previous view from super view and add a new view as subview.

```
[myView1 removeFromSuperview];
myView2.frame = CGRectMake(...);
[self.view addSubview: myView2];
```